# Locking / Hiding cells in Excel containing tables and formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet with Table in it. As we know, the cells contained in the table column are updated automatically based on the formula in the first cell in a given column by virtue of tables' nature in Excel.
There are formulas within the tables (with references in other worksheets too) which will update the results in other columns in the same table.
All I wanted to do was to protect the formulas (within the table) by locking and hiding the contents of those cells. I could do it as described here [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214081].
The problem is if i added more data to the table the results are not being updated now.
Is there a way, where i could lock /hide the cells with formulas but still update the table.
I'm thinking of the next option of moving all the formula cells to another worksheet and make it "very hidden" from VBA editor.

My source file is here "[my workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GWUz9wG4bHeVfqvPB8EqFhcAiGgFDVEjZDoycp1QAWw/edit#gid=1096977041)"
The table spans from A to AH 
If I change in the values in the columns D to M (input columns), it will update results in columns N to Q (final outputs). Intermediate calculations are stored in columns R to AH. I want to lock and hide R to AH.
[image]

Comment: Is [hiding the columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/show-or-hide-columns-and-rows-HP010342574.aspx) an option, or do you need the data in that part of the table visible?

Comment: The objective is to protect the data. Hiding does not give enough protection. For example accidental deletion of columns with formulas. I will circulate this file as a tool for others to use.

Comment: Protecting it like the article you linked seems to fit your purpose. I don't understand you your data isn't updated then anymore. [Here is a clear explanation](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/protect-few-columns-in-the-spread-sheet-excel/).

Comment: After I lock my cells (as per the instructions from the article) and  if I enter new values to the excel "table" - it does not auto update - as a part of the "table" cells are locked. If you have time please see my file to understand the situation better...